# x86 Argument has Illegal Size [tasm]

Tags: assembly, tasm

I have this task to change a string of numbers(`<=100`) by the following rule: `nr becomes 1 if it's less tham 60 and 2 if not`. I came out with this code. I thought the biggest challenge was to print the numbers... but it gives me 2 errors pointed as marked on the code:

```
Prints macro number
    mov bx, 10      ; need to divide by 10 to get the last digit
    mov al, number
    mov ah,0
    mov cx,0
    decompose:      
        inc cx
        div bx          ; reminder stored in ah
        mov dl,ah
        add dl,48       ; to convert to char ; <<<<< HERE
        push dl
        cmp al,0        ;the nr=0 means that the loop ends
        jnz decompose

    printloop:  ;loops for as many times as counted in cx ; <<<< HERE
        pop dl  
        mov ah,2h       ; prints whatever is in dl
        int 21h
    loop printloop

        mov dl,' '      ; the space after a number
        mov ah,2h
        int 21h

endm

data segment para public 'data'
    sir DB 15, 78, 12, 39, 42, 88
    lungime_sir EQU $-sir
data ends

;stack segment para public 'stack'
;   dw stack_size dup(?)
;   stack_start label word
;stack ends

code segment para public 'code'
start proc far
    assume cs:code, ds:data
    push ds
    xor ax,ax
    push ax
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax

    mov si,0
    mov cx,lungime_sir

next: 
    cmp sir[si],60
    jb mic
    mov sir[si],2
    inc si
loop next

mic: 
    mov sir[si],1
    inc si
    cmp si,lungime_sir
    jle next


    mov cx,lungime_sir
    mov si,0

    ;put values on a stack and pop them out 
print:
    Prints sir[si]
    inc si

loop print


        ret
start endp
code ends
end start
```

What's wrong? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `push dl` and `pop dl` into `push dx` and `pop dx`. You cannot push/pop a byte.

```
div bx          ; reminder stored in ah
```

Change this divide into `div bl` to obtain the remainder in AH.

Put `mov ah,0` after the label *decompose* to get successful second and third iterations

```
mov cx,0
decompose: 
mov ah,0
```

You've defined **Prints** as a macro that doesn't preserve any registers. So the following code will not work as expected. At least push/pop CX.

```
print:
 Prints sir[si]
 inc si
loop print
```

Comment: I did that, thank you. Now I have another problem, with the algorithm apparently. For "32" it's printing "2000781.....152" :/

Comment: I can assure you that it is not! Look at the code at the label *next* . Each time the value is smaller than 60 you forget to decrement CX. It looks like it's working but that's a coincidence (CX and SI **in this particular case** are interchangeable)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, in my code I changed the loop for a jbe (cmp si,lungime_sir), I just didn't correct it here.